# How do I append the src attributes to a set of images after they have loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

Here is my scenario:

I am having a page with pagination and enhanced with infinite-scroll

The page has a list of items, where each item looks like this in smarty

```
<div id="link-{index}">
<div align="left"><a href={$url}></div><div alight="right"><img src="" id="{$url}"></div>
</div> <script>imager({$url});</script>
```

I am using a service to dynamically grab image src for a given URL and append it to the image by defining `imager(x){ document.getElementById(x).src =  service(x).image; }`

Now this works, as in shows correct images along side URLs as long as normal pagination is used. Doesn't work for page 2 onwards with infinite scroll as it uses JQuery and that parses out the imager JS script for each item.

I am stuck with trying to create a callback function for infinite scroll that will do what imager does but after a page is loaded but I am unable to get it to work.

Any tips will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Check the documentation of your infinite scroll plugin to see if it has a callback when a new page is loaded. Then use this to add `src` attributes to the new images.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do but am new to jQuery and little experience with JS. Is there a way to loop through just the last n images from the new page fetched by infinite scroll to append their srcs?

Answer (score 0):

In the callback for when a new page is loaded, you can do something like this:

```
$('img:not([src])').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', service($(this).attr('id')).image);
});
```

This assumes that the only images without a source are those that were just loaded by the infinite scroller. If the widget provides parameters to the callback that tells it which parts of the DOM were just paged in, you may be able to use that to narrow down further; the second argument to a jQuery selector is the context to search.